# decorator pattern decorator limit

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

I am currently writing a program using the decorator pattern. I am trying to find out how to limit the amount of decorators I can add to the first class. Such as:

```
Pizza plainPizza = new PlainPizza;
Pizza sausage = new Sausage(plainPizza);
```

How could I code this where I can be limited to the amount of decorators I add on. Such as if I try to add this on top of the previous code:

```
Pizza pepperoni = new Pepperoni(sausage);
```

How can I prevent it from allowing pepperoni to be added/wrapped?

I am attempting to use a throw exception, but the problem is, my decorators call its superclass, so I can't test before initializing the instance variable!

Comment: You can't. That's the point of the decorator pattern.

Comment: Sounds more like the decorator pattern is not the right pattern for your use case.

Comment: @XaverKapeller This is what my professor is having us do in a lab. This is one of many tasks. Have no idea what to do. I am attempting to throw exceptions, but I can't, because I call the super before the test for count can occur.

Comment: Well as I told you it's not possible. Also throwing exceptions here would be terrible from an api perspective. What ever you do to impose this constraint would cause this to stop being the decorator pattern.

Comment: What's the function of your decorators? Calculating cost for toppings? I agree the problem the pattern solves (wrapping ) doesn't seem to make sense with limiting.

Comment: Since this is a [homework](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) question, please show the code of the solution which you've attempted, and explain the part of your code that isn't working.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I agree with this, but since this is what I was told to do, I just ended up throwing an exception when there were too many decorators. Apparently, throwing an exception was what I was supposed to do!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to create a builder that will apply all types of decorators that you need. Builder could also internally keep track of how many decorators you applied and react accordingly if attempt to add more than it's allowed is made.